# Would like to reduce jQuery that have similar code for 3 forms validation in ajax

Tags: jquery

I want to use 3 forms for newsletter subscription. The jquery code that validate fields and push the form with ajax is very similar in all forms. Could you help me to reduce and optimize this code ? Here is exemple, you see two of my forms...

First, there is some vars in each form that are used in the following code. After that, there is validation that is same for each form. If all is OK, I push the form in ajax; the ajax code is very similar in every form.

Thanks !!

```
        $('#signup-sidebar').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // Vérification des erreurs dans les champs
        // Basé sur : https://teamtreehouse.com/community/create-a-simple-validation-form-using-jquery

        var $newsletterform_sb = $("#signup-sidebar");
        var $newsletteremail_sb = $("#sidebar-email");
        var $newsletteraccept_sb = $("#sidebar-policy");
        var $newsletterresponse_sb = $("#response-sidebar");
        var errors_sb = false;
        var emailReg = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9\\-\\_\\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$/i;

        // Le courriel est absent ou invalide
        if ($newsletteremail_sb.val() === "Votre courriel") {
            $newsletteremail_sb.addClass('commenterrorfield').val("Entrez votre courriel");
            $newsletteremail_sb.on('click focusin', function() {
                $(this).removeClass().val("");
            });
            errors_sb = true;

        } else if (!emailReg.test($newsletteremail_sb.val())) {
            $newsletteremail_sb.addClass('commenterrorfield').val("Adresse invalide"); 
            $newsletteremail_sb.on('click focusin', function() {
                $(this).removeClass().val("");
            });
            errors_sb = true;
        }

        if ($newsletteraccept_sb.is(":not(:checked)")) {
            $newsletterresponse_sb.show().attr('class', 'fielderror').html('Vous devez accepter la politique de confidentialité');
            $newsletteraccept_sb.on('click focusin', function() {
                $newsletterresponse_sb.attr('class', 'fielderrorhide');
            });
            errors_sb = true;
        }

        // S'il y a des erreurs, on blogue l'envoi
        if (errors_sb) {
            event.preventDefault(); // empêche la soumission du formulaire non ajax

        // Sinon on procède avec l'ajax...
        } else {

            $newsletterresponse_sb.attr('class', 'response-sidebar').html('Vérification des informations...').hide().fadeIn(200);
            $.ajax({
                url: ''+ template_url +'/mailchimp/inscriptions-v2.php',
                type: 'POST', // <- IMPORTANT
                data: $newsletterform_sb.serialize() + '&ajax=true',
                success: function(msg) {
                    var message = $.parseJSON(msg),
                        result = '';
                    if (message.status === 'pending') { // succès
                        result = 'Merci ! Un courriel vous a été envoyé pour confirmer votre inscription.';
                    } else { // erreur
                        //result = 'Erreur : ' + message.detail;
                        result = 'Erreur ! Adresse non valide ou peut-être déjà inscrite.';
                    }
                    $newsletterresponse_sb.html(result); // affichage du message
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    });

    /*
    * Script Newsletter footer
    */

    $('#signup-footer').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // Vérification des erreurs dans les champs
        // Basé sur : https://teamtreehouse.com/community/create-a-simple-validation-form-using-jquery

        var $newsletterform_ft = $("#signup-footer");
        var $newsletteremail_ft = $("#footer-email");
        var $newsletteraccept_ft = $("#footer-policy");
        var $newsletterresponse_ft = $("#response-footer");
        var errors_sb = false;
        var emailReg = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9\\-\\_\\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$/i;

        // Le courriel est absent ou invalide
        if ($newsletteremail_ft.val() === "Votre courriel") {
            $newsletteremail_ft.addClass('commenterrorfield').val("Entrez votre courriel");
            $newsletteremail_ft.on('click focusin', function() {
                $(this).removeClass().val("");
            });
            errors_sb = true;

        } else if (!emailReg.test($newsletteremail_ft.val())) {
            $newsletteremail_ft.addClass('commenterrorfield').val("Adresse invalide"); 
            $newsletteremail_ft.on('click focusin', function() {
                $(this).removeClass().val("");
            });
            errors_sb = true;
        }

        if ($newsletteraccept_ft.is(":not(:checked)")) {
            $newsletterresponse_ft.show().attr('class', 'fielderror').html('Vous devez accepter la politique de confidentialité');
            $newsletteraccept_ft.on('click focusin', function() {
                $newsletterresponse_ft.attr('class', 'fielderrorhide');
            });
            errors_sb = true;
        }

        // S'il y a des erreurs, on blogue l'envoi
        if (errors_sb) {
            event.preventDefault(); // empêche la soumission du formulaire non ajax

        // Sinon on procède avec l'ajax...
        } else {

            $newsletterresponse_ft.attr('class', 'response-footer').html('Vérification des informations...').hide().fadeIn(200);
            $.ajax({
                url: ''+ template_url +'/mailchimp/inscriptions-v2.php',
                type: 'POST', // <- IMPORTANT
                data: $newsletterform_ft.serialize() + '&ajax=true',
                success: function(msg) {
                    var message = $.parseJSON(msg),
                        result = '';
                    if (message.status === 'pending') { // succès
                        result = 'Merci ! Un courriel vous a été envoyé pour confirmer votre inscription.';
                    } else { // erreur
                        //result = 'Erreur : ' + message.detail;
                        result = 'Erreur ! Adresse non valide ou peut-être déjà inscrite.';
                    }
                    $newsletterresponse_ft.html(result); // affichage du message
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the code you gave you could do a refactor to reuse the same functions like this:

```
    ['sidebar', 'footer'].forEach(function(el) {
        $('#signup-' + el).submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            // Vérification des erreurs dans les champs
            // Basé sur : https://teamtreehouse.com/community/create-a-simple-validation-form-using-jquery

           validateForm(el)
        });
    })

    function validateForm(selector) {

            var $newsletterform_sb = $("#signup-" + selector);
            var $newsletteremail_sb = $("#"+selector+"-email");
            var $newsletteraccept_sb = $("#"+selector+"-policy");
            var $newsletterresponse_sb = $("#response-"+selector);
            var errors_sb = false;
            var emailReg = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9\\-\\_\\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$/i;

            // Le courriel est absent ou invalide
            if ($newsletteremail_sb.val() === "Votre courriel") {
                $newsletteremail_sb.addClass('commenterrorfield').val("Entrez votre courriel");
                $newsletteremail_sb.on('click focusin', function() {
                    $(this).removeClass().val("");
                });
                errors_sb = true;

            } else if (!emailReg.test($newsletteremail_sb.val())) {
                $newsletteremail_sb.addClass('commenterrorfield').val("Adresse invalide"); 
                $newsletteremail_sb.on('click focusin', function() {
                    $(this).removeClass().val("");
                });
                errors_sb = true;
            }

            if ($newsletteraccept_sb.is(":not(:checked)")) {
                $newsletterresponse_sb.show().attr('class', 'fielderror').html('Vous devez accepter la politique de confidentialité');
                $newsletteraccept_sb.on('click focusin', function() {
                    $newsletterresponse_sb.attr('class', 'fielderrorhide');
                });
                errors_sb = true;
            }

            // S'il y a des erreurs, on blogue l'envoi
            if (errors_sb) {
                event.preventDefault(); // empêche la soumission du formulaire non ajax

                // Sinon on procède avec l'ajax...
            } else {
                sendForm($newsletterform_sb, $newsletterresponse_sb, 'response-'+selector)
                return false;
            }
    }

    function sendForm(form, response, elClass) {
          response.attr('class', elClass).html('Vérification des informations...').hide().fadeIn(200);
          $.ajax({
              url: ''+ template_url +'/mailchimp/inscriptions-v2.php',
              type: 'POST', // <- IMPORTANT
              data: form.serialize() + '&ajax=true',
              success: function(msg) {
                  var message = $.parseJSON(msg),
                  result = '';
                  if (message.status === 'pending') { // succès
                    result = 'Merci ! Un courriel vous a été envoyé pour confirmer votre inscription.';
                  } else { // erreur
                      //result = 'Erreur : ' + message.detail;
                      result = 'Erreur ! Adresse non valide ou peut-être déjà inscrite.';
                  }
                  response.html(result); // affichage du message
              }
          });
      }
```

Comment: Wow @Laura I cant believe it !!! It works like a charm ! You passed my code from 212 lines to 77 (with some added modifications before you posted your answer. So many thanks for your quick reply and your time...

Comment: @DominicDesbiens no problem, I know it's not an habit in France but you should your comments in English too ;)

Comment: Haha... I'm from Quebec, Canada. We speak mostly in french here. Since I am the only one working with this code I do not systematically put all my comments in English. I will consider your suggestion. Thanks a lot again !!!